# Unable to start service

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to start a service but I get an error.
I have no idea how to solve this specific problem.
The class I am starting the service form:

```
package com.example.test;

public class Purchase extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this,MyHostApduService.class);
        Livedate<User> user = *something*;
        user.observe(Purchase.this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
                i.putExtra("user name", user.getUserName());
                i.putExtra("credit card", user.getCreditCard());
                i.putExtra("context", Purchase.class);
                i.putExtra("mail", user.getMail());
            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(Purchase.this, "YOU CAN ONLY MAKE A PURCHASE AFTER GETTING CLOSE TO THE OTHER DEVICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.startService(i);
    }

}
```

the service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    creditCard = intent.getExtras().getString("credit card");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.test.MyHostApduService@fe81f37 with Intent { cmp=com.example.test/.MyHostApduService }: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent that you are passing to the service does not have the property "credit card". This is because you are starting the service with an empty intent (no extras). The code `i.putExtra("credit card", user.getCreditCard());` is only executed when there is a change to the LiveData. When the activity first starts, there is nothing triggering LiveData's onChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading about event loops here, there are a few good articles out there if you search for "android event loop".

Effectively what is happening is that your method "onCreate" and "onChanged" are both callbacks.  "onCreate" will execute completely before "onChanged" can start.  This means you start the service with no arguments getting the null pointer exception.  As a general rule you don't want to use an object across multiple callbacks if avoidable.

One possible way around this is to start the service when new data comes in.  But be careful what happens if multiple changes in the user data are possible.

```
package com.example.test;

public class Purchase extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);
        Livedate<User> user = *something*;
        user.observe(Purchase.this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
                final Intent i = new Intent(this,MyHostApduService.class);
                i.putExtra("user name", user.getUserName());
                i.putExtra("credit card", user.getCreditCard());
                i.putExtra("context", Purchase.class);
                i.putExtra("mail", user.getMail());
                Purchase.this.startService(i);
                Toast...
            }
        });
    }
}
```